# unable to write data correctly to firebase firestore

Tags: flutter

I am a beginner at flutter, and am trying to design my own app, which has user login and signup as a part of it. I have written the code to add a user to my database when sign up is clicked, and also to add a few parameters to a collection called 'Users'. The first part does work, and user auth takes place, but the parameters given are not added to the collection

have attached the code for signup for reference

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'updateScreen.dart';
//import 'home.dart';
import 'welcomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class SignupScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignupScreenState createState() => _SignupScreenState();
}

class _SignupScreenState extends State<SignupScreen> {


  String emailId = '';
  String userName = '';
  String password = '';
  String confirmPassword = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "SIGNUP SCREEN",
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.teal,
        ),
        width: 900,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(
                top: 150,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 700, maxWidth: 300),
                )),
            Positioned(
              top: 200,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 400,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        maxLength: 15,
                        maxLengthEnforced: true,
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          focusColor: Colors.black,
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.teal,
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                          hintText: 'enter your user name',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.verified_user),
                        ),
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                        onChanged: (val) {
                          setState(() {
                            emailId = val;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 400,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            focusColor: Colors.black,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.teal,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                            hintText: 'enter your email ID',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.email),
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              emailId = val;
                            });
                          },
                          validator: (val) {
                            return val.contains('@')
                                ? null
                                : 'please enter a valid email';
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 400,
                        child: TextFormField(
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            focusColor: Colors.black,
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.teal,
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                            hintText: 'enter your password',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            icon: Icon(Icons.admin_panel_settings_outlined),
                          ),
                          obscureText: true,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              password = val;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                        minWidth: 200.0,
                        height: 50.0,
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          elevation: 14.0,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                          onPressed: () {
                            try {
                              FirebaseAuth.instance
                                  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                      email: emailId, password: password);
                              signup(context);
                              userSetup();
                            } catch (e) {
                              return e.message;
                            }
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "SIGN UP",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void signup(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => UpdatesScreen(),
        ));
  }

}
  Future<void> userSetup() async {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    String uid = auth.currentUser.uid.toString();
    users.add(
        {'email_id': emailId, 'user_name': userName, 'user_identifier': uid});
        print("user added to db");
        return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is an async method meaning it doesn't complete its execution immediately, for your `userSetup` method to work, you should affix `await` before `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.
2. print the error, rather than returning a string.

I have put in comments below, the stuffs you need to take care, there are 5 points. This should help you to dig more into your problems.

```
 onPressed: async(){
try{
     //1. affix await before createUserWithEmailAndPassword
     await FirebaseAuth.instance
                   .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                     email: emailId, password: password);
   //2. call userSetup before navigating to next page, also sinc user setup also 
   //has an async operation, affix this method with async too.
    await userSetup();
  //3. if all the above methods execute successfully, navigate to next page
   signup(context); 
}
//4. instead of return, use print to get notified about errors.
catch (e){
print(e)
}
}
```

```
Future<void> userSetup() async {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    String uid = auth.currentUser.uid.toString();
// 5. affix await before add 
    await users.add(
        {'email_id': emailId, 'user_name': userName, 'user_identifier': uid});
        print("user added to db");
        return;
  }
```